# persistant cookies using nodejs

Tags: node.js, cookies, express

I want to save some cookies in my browser using node.js. Any one knows how I can achieve this behavior? My purpose is when the user has checked the checkbox("keep me logged in") then the checkbox state and the cookies should be stored.